# Help me with dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

When I try to install .deb file it says:

```
Selecting previously unselected package guitarpro6:i386.
(Reading database ... 182150 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gp6-full-linux-demo-r11686(1).deb ...
Unpacking guitarpro6:i386 (6.1.9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of guitarpro6:i386:
guitarpro6:i386 depends on gksu.
guitarpro6:i386 depends on libasound2; however:
Package libasound2:i386 is not installed.
guitarpro6:i386 depends on libglu1-mesa; however:
Package libglu1-mesa:i386 is not installed.
guitarpro6:i386 depends on libportaudio2; however:
guitarpro6:i386 depends on libstdc++6; however:
Package libstdc++6:i386 is not installed.
guitarpro6:i386 depends on libxml2; however:
Package libxml2:i386 is not installed.
guitarpro6:i386 depends on libxslt1.1; however:
Package libxslt1.1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package guitarpro6:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
guitarpro6:i386
```

How do I fix this? I don't even know what to install.

`sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` gives me:

```
Selecting previously unselected package guitarpro6:i386.
(Reading database ... 182150 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gp6-full-linux-demo-r11686(1).deb ...
Unpacking guitarpro6:i386 (6.1.9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of guitarpro6:i386:
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on gksu.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libasound2; however:
  Package libasound2:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libglu1-mesa; however:
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libportaudio2; however:
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libstdc++6; however:
  Package libstdc++6:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libxml2; however:
  Package libxml2:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libxslt1.1; however:
  Package libxslt1.1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package guitarpro6:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 guitarpro6:i386
matjaz@X555LN:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 guitarpro6:i386 : Depends: gksu:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libasound2:i386
                   Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libportaudio2:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libxml2:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install --fix-missing gives me:

```
Selecting previously unselected package guitarpro6:i386.
(Reading database ... 182150 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gp6-full-linux-demo-r11686(1).deb ...
Unpacking guitarpro6:i386 (6.1.9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of guitarpro6:i386:
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on gksu.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libasound2; however:
  Package libasound2:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libglu1-mesa; however:
  Package libglu1-mesa:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libportaudio2; however:
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libstdc++6; however:
  Package libstdc++6:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libxml2; however:
  Package libxml2:i386 is not installed.
 guitarpro6:i386 depends on libxslt1.1; however:
  Package libxslt1.1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package guitarpro6:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 guitarpro6:i386
matjaz@X555LN:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 guitarpro6:i386 : Depends: gksu:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libasound2:i386
                   Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libportaudio2:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libxml2:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: only 'answers' of the above question should be posted here.. respond through comments or editing the actual post.